# Trouble updating child component data on another child component after input

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that has 4 child components,those 4 child components share some fields, when i add a new property to one of those components i want the data to be updated on other child components, how do i do that without reloading the page?

I have tried making a function in the parent component that initialises all the data for the child components and i call it in the constructor, so each time i change between the components on the web page the function that initialises the fields is called and all the fields are updated with the right data, but that is not a very efficient way to do it because the function i called each time i click on something, so the solution i came up with is to make a ngOnInit method in the parent component that will initialise the fields and fill them with new data each time a child component is updated, but i don't know how to call the ngOnInit method when a child component is updated.

so what i need is to call the ngOnInit in the parent component each time a child component field is updated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show your code, rather than describing it. This helps everyone to identify errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would just declare a behaviour subject like this.

private behaviourSub = new BehaviorSubject(initialValue);

and all you have to do is subscribe to this behaviour subject and you can emit value afterwards.

behaviourSub.next(newValue);

you can subscibe it across components just keep it in one service.